# Как перевести 4 байта DWORD в читаемую строку

Tags: php, строки, файлы, байты

У меня имеется файл, в начале которого содержится 4 байта DWORD с некоторым id и я без понятия как его сделать читабельным.

Описание к файлу: 4 byte - DWORD - section identifier

Мои действия: я получаю содержимое файла в виде строки, считываю первые 4 байта файла и вывожу с помощью json_encode

Результат: "\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000"

Немногословно, конечно же, поэтому я прошу вашей помощи

Comment: То есть, на выходе должна получиться строка "10000"?

Comment: Покажите, как вы их считываете